# Broken inline datePicker as InputView for TextField Swift iOS 14

Tags: swift, datepicker, inline, ios14

I use new inline Date Picker that is available from iOS 13.4 as inputView for Text Field(before I used wheels). However, it looks broken as the height of inputView is constant: [How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXob6.png)

I have tried changing the frame and disable AutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints. It didn't help. The way it should work is like a default inline datePicker. [How dataPicker should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpCMc.png)

To sum up, I need to increase the height of custom InputView for UITextField.

Comment: Does "it looks broken" because "the height of the inputView is constant"? If so, is your question: How can the height of the inputView be changed?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Sorry, forgot to sum up. Yes, the main concern is how to increase the height of custom InputView for UITextField. Thanks!

Comment: It might be helpful to edit your question to "sum up". Sometimes comments are not read by those that might answer your question.

Comment: I see. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I Guess it was limited by default height of inputView.
Just change the Size of it then works.

```
// You can change value as you want. I think same with screen width is better for me. 
let scrWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
textfield.inputView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: scrWidth, height: scrWidth)
// Changing CGRect also can work
textfieldinputView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrWidth , height: scrWidth)
```

[Result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1re0B.png)

Interesting, when I tested on SE1, it showed up as normal without using above method, and the inputView size was 320*353.3

[inputView on SE1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6gOJ.png)

But the height of other devices larger than it will limited to some value (IDK what is the reference.)

The limitation here was 355.666667, and the size would be 414*355.6667

[inputView on 11 Pro Max](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIP6X.png)

So that's why I guess dataPicker just get cropped when scaled up.

Answer (score 0):

```
let scrWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
textField.inputView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: scrWidth, height: scrWidth + 50)
datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrWidth , height: scrWidth + 50)
```